# Transforming CRS of Spatial Polygon Data Frame?

Tags: r, sf

The code below shows the outline of Canada obtained from [GDAM](https://gadm.org/) as a Spatial Polygons Dataframe with a CRS of EPSG:4326. I wish to transform this to EPSG:3857 (Mercator). Yet, I obtain the following error.

Why?

```
Error in UseMethod("st_transform") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_transform' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial', 'SpatialVector')"
```

==========

```
library(mapdata)
library(sf)

# Get Canada as spatial polygons data frame
# GADM data is +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
# CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
canada <- getData("GADM", country = "CAN", level = 1)

# Transform to Mercator projection *** ERROR ***
canada_t <- st_transform(canada, "+init=epsg:3857")
```

Comment: First, check the class of you object. In your example it is likely sp and not sf. Second look at spTransform.

Comment: Or convert Canada to an `sf` with `canada = st_as_sf(canada)`

Comment: Also, `getData` needs `library(raster)`, and not `mapdata`